# Swapping rows and columns in a matrix in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I want to analyse the sales of a certain company in Power Bi. I have a customer dataset with nine columns (gender, city, age range, hair colour etc.) and one million records. Now I want to put those columns in a matrix. For instance:

- Rows: Gender
- Columns: Age Range (<16, 17-20, 21-25 etc.)
- Values: Number of Sales

I present this dashboard towards some people and I want to 'play' with the data. What happens if I change the rows to 'hair colour' for instance. Is there a way to do this without using bookmarks? In one sentence: swapping rows and columns of a matrix while you present the dashboard and cannot use the option 'Fields'? Or at least point me in the right direction? It would really help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the quickest way to do this is using the Fields pane. The only other option that is available would be Bookmarks, but I guess you have already tried that. I guess you are an option similar to the one available in "Pivot Charts" where you can "Switch Rows/Columns" with the click of a button. That option is not available in Power BI at this point, as far as I know.